# tsconfig.paths not working with ES modules

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, ts-node

I switched my project to enable ES modules:

- added `type: module` in package.json
- use `node --loader ts-node/esm` instead of `ts-node`
- changed `module: commonjs` to `esnext`

It works fine, except when starting using paths aliases.

so,  `import test from './file';` works, but  `import test from '@app/file';` doesn't work

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-wlm8vs?file=index.ts)